# Question about Matlab's aerospace toolbox's gravitysphericalharmonic library

Tags: matlab, coordinates, gravity

I'm currently trying to learn how to use the gravity models that Matlab's 'gravitysphericalharmonics' library has. In this documentation: https://www.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/gravitysphericalharmonic.html#mw_3bdd1e99-46be-4fd5-8b7c-6dd710546616

It gives us two examples:

1. Calculate the gravity in the x-axis at the equator on the surface of Earth. This example uses the default 120 degree model of EGM2008 with default warning actions.

```
gx = gravitysphericalharmonic([-6378.137e3 0 0])
```

2. Calculate the gravity at 25,000 m over the south pole of Earth.

```
[gx, gy, gz] = gravitysphericalharmonic([0 0 -6381.751e3],'EGM96','Error')
```

Here's my question, how did they get -6381.751e3 for the second question if they're just finding the gravity 25,000m above the surface of Earth? If Earth's radius is ~6378.137e3 meters, then calculating the gravity at 25,000m above Earth would just be the radius + 25,000 meters right?

Lastly, I wanted to just ask someone with more knowledge about this module why it was -6378.137e3 m for the first question. If we're taking the coordinate from just the surface of Earth, wouldn't that number have to be positive?

Sorry if this doesn't make any sense, I'm new to this stuff and I really want to learn! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The first example uses a 3D position vector, in a coordinate system with its origin at the center of the planet (Earth).  The position vector[-6378.137e3 0 0] is on the equator, as is [6378.137e3 0 0] (they are on opposite sides of the world).  Any other position vector with magnitude 6378.137e3 and a Z component (the third number) of 0 would also be on the equator.

The Earth is not a perfect sphere; it is an oblate spheroid.  The [radius at the equator is 6378.137 km, but the radius at the poles is 6356.752 km](https://nssdc.gsfc.nasa.gov/planetary/factsheet/earthfact.html).  Their documentation is not great here, but they have arrived at the position vector in the second example by taking this polar radius and increasing the magnitude of the vector by 15 km.  The Z component is negative because this example is at the South Pole; if the Z component were positive, it would be at the North Pole.  Because it is negative, they have to add -15 km to get to a point that is 15 km above the surface (but if you were looking at a globe, and holding the globe so that north is up, that point would be below the globe).

They have probably used examples with negative values in the position vector precisely to ensure that people ask themselves the kinds of questions that you are asking.

The aerospace toolbox also provides a function [ecef2lla](https://www.mathworks.com/help/aerotbx/ug/ecef2lla.html) to convert these position vectors into latitude, longitude, and altitude, which may help you understand them.